# Apache2 mod_rewrite not fetching .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Using a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 with Apache2 (using virtual hosts), however I cannot get .htaccess to rewrite my URL as needs be.
Consider:

000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/radio/
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: you may need to enable the rewrite module in Apache --  IE `sudo a2enmod rewrite`   THen `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: @Zak Already done that pal.

Comment: Is the rewrite working when you put your RewriteRules into the <Directory> ? Are the permissions on .htaccess correct?

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file located? If you put some _nonsense_ at the start of your `.htaccess` file, do you get an error?

Comment: Why would you want to use a distributed configuration file (".htaccess") with all the disadvantages if you have control over the actual http server's host configuration?